# Can't figure out how to style material ui datagrid

Tags: material-ui

I'm trying to style material-ui `DataGrid` component to justify the content in the cells. I am reading the material ui docs about styling but I don't seem to doing it correct and frankly find the docs on styling **very** confusing.

The doc here: https://material-ui.com/customization/components/#overriding-styles-with-classes implies I should be able to do something like this:

```
const StyledDataGrid = withStyles({
  cellCenter: {
    justifyContent: "center",
  },
})(DataGrid);

<div style={{ height: 300, width: '100%' }}>
  <StyledDataGrid rows={rows} columns={columns} />
</div>
```

However, when I do this, I don't see the style being added to the MuiDataGrid-cellCenter DOM element. Attaching a screenshot which shows the element classes. In the inspector I see that the style isn't being added (and if I add it manually I get the desired results). Am I not using the withStyles function correctly?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

So after a bit more messing around, I believe the issue is that the DataGrid component does not support the `classes` property (which it seems most of the material ui components do). I believe the withStyles usage about is shorthand for passing the classes via the classes prop. Since the prop isn't listed in the API https://material-ui.com/api/data-grid/ I'm assuming this is why it isn't working. I confirmed that I can get the styles working by using a combination of the className parameter with descendant selection.

**If someone determines I'm wrong and there is a way to get withStyles working on this component please comment.**

```
const useStyles = makeStyles({
  root: {
    "& .MuiDataGrid-cellCenter": {
      justifyContent: "center"
    }
  }
});

... 

export default function X() {

  const classes = useStyles();

  return (
   ...
   <DataGrid className={classes.root} checkboxSelection={true} rows={rows} columns={columns} />
   ...
  )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**ALTERNATIVE SOLUTION: (for others with similar issues)**

If you are working within a **class** and cannot use hooks...

```
<div>
    <DataGrid
        rows={rows}
        columns={columns}
        sx={{
            '&.MuiDataGrid-root .MuiDataGrid-cell:focus': {
                outline: 'none',
            },
        }}
    />
</div>
```